# What are the rules of Station Building so the AI can find you?

Tags: x-rebirth

In earlier installments of the series, it was always important that the AI finds you and you tended to build your station close to the main routes of the AI in the sector you have been in.

However, this is different in Rebirth. There is no such stream of ships like in previous X Games, they are either around stations or inside the highways. You can basically just exit the highway anywhere where it is empty and build a station if you like.

But, will the AI actually find your station? What are the "rules" here to make sure the AI Traders find and use your station?

Comment: How far into the game are you? Have you got past the E-Cell delivery mission? How did you do it?

Comment: @MrUniverse I'd recommend starting a freeplay game just to explore, that's what I'm doing anyway until the stupid quest gets straightened out.

Comment: Pretty sure the AI always was instantly aware of all stations in previous X games.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can't actually build stations wherever you want. You are limited to a couple spots per zone, as far as I can tell. Yet another removed feature.

Comment: at least we can hope, this points is accessible for AI.